# Asking for some sources of country-level data regarding technology literacy, cashless level, financial moneytary policy, and financial stability

Tags: economics

I am looking for the sources for these variables (country-level), as many countries as possible about: the technology literacy levels, cashless level, financial monetary policy, and financial stability system of each country.

Regarding the financial stability, I found a source from [Bo Sun](https://sites.google.com/site/bosun09/monetary-policy-uncertainty-index) but they just cover 22 countries

Comment: You may want to start at https://www.worldpop.org/

Comment: thanks, it looks like they just provided data for some continents

Comment: https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/listing?id=23 (for example) lists data for individual countries, but not all of them. It's not just continents.